# Unique ID for year

Tags: php, uniqueidentifier

Im looking for how to generate a unique id that will remain unique for one year. I use `uniqid()` function but I've heard that there is a chance for duplicates, so I do this:
$id = rand(0,1000) . uniqid();

Will this remain unique for a whole year?

Comment: What's wrong with using the year itself as a unique ID?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Wouldn't the year number be a unique ID in itself? Can you clarify?

Comment: i mean that there wont be any duplicates while year.

Comment: That's not even close to unique. Why are you limiting it to a year anyway. Why not just have a unique id, and if you want to know what year it is store that as well.

Comment: I tried to clarify your question based on your comment (that is now gone). Hope this helps stem off the down votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to be sure you have a unique Id in your data set is to test for it.

```
$id = uniqid(2012); //returns a 13 character string plus it will append 2012 for 17 characters.
$resultSet = //get dataSet from somewhere

foreach($resultSet as $row) {
    if ($row['id'] = $id) {
    //do some stuff
   }
}
```

This is a simple example of how you might flow this in a simple application. I'm sure there is probably a way to do this SQL as well (but I don't know SQL that well).

Alternatively you could just let the database start at 1 and assign each record a *unique* value for it's ID.

You failed to mention your purpose so these suggestions are a best guess.

Good Luck.